# libsvn - svn_pool_create() - Unresolved external

Tags: c++, svn, visual-c++

I've been playing with libsvn. I'm trying to just do a simple checkout.

I've got the code I think would work, however I can't compile it due to an unresolved external.

[[see my code here]](http://pastebin.com/6ZzPvpBj)

I have the following libraries linked statically:

- libsvn-client-1.lib
- libapr-1.lib

However, Which library file contains the declaration for the function svn_create_pool()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it!

- libsvn_subr-1.lib

It was ridiculous how I found it.

Used the windows command:

```
     dir *.lib /b
```

This gave me a list of libraries which I then tested and allowed me to keep halving the list to finally find it.